# Polymorphic Relationship: Routes & Activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to figure out polymorphic relationships and I keep getting the following errors with my routes whenever I try to add an index to show all + with activeadmin.

Error 1:  I have tried numerous different variations for this, sometimes I get an error, other times no error but nothing appears.

Error 2:  **NameError in Admin::Places#index, uninitialized constant Place::FavoritePlace,  insert_tag renderer_for(:index)** 
 ---> For this error, I have tried to add in the remove_filter :favorites (and different variations on that), but that solution did not work.

I have a model, places, which I want users to be able to add a place to a list of favorites.  I would like a page that shows all favorites by current user.  The user is able to favorite/un-favorite a place as of now.  Would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

**place.rb**

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base 
  #Favorites
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_places, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Place'
end
```

**favorite.rb**

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :place
end
```

**favorite_places_controller.rb**

```
class FavoritePlacesController < ApplicationController

   before_action :set_place,  except: [:index]

 def index
  @places = User.favorite_places
 end
 def create
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @place, user: current_user)
    redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place has been favorited'
  else
    redirect_to @place, alert: 'Something went wrong. *womp womp*'
  end
end

def destroy
  Favorite.where(favorited_id: @place.id, user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
  redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place is no longer a favorite'
end

private

 def set_place
   @place = Place.find(params[:place_id] || params[:id])
 end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
#favorites
 resources :favorite_places
```

**views/favorite_places/index.html.erb**

```
<% @places.each do |place| %>     
  <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <div id="image-wrapper">
      <span itemprop="photo"><%= link_to image_tag(place.image.url(:medium)), place, class: "hover" %></span>

       <p class="image-text text-center"> <span itemprop="name">
             <%= place.name %>
         </span>
        <br>

        <span itemprop="servesCuisine"><%= ["beer", "chocolate" ,"cocktail", "coffee", "tea", "wine", "juice"] [place.kind] %>
        </span>
      </p>

    </div>

 </div>
<% end %>
```

**admin/place.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Place do

   controller do
     def permitted_params
      params.permit place: [ :city_id, :description, :image_file_name, :image_content_type, :image_file_size, :name, :kind, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :website, :dress, :food, ":image_updated_at(1i)", ":image_updated_at(2i)", ":image_updated_at(3i)", ":image_updated_at(4i)", ":image_updated_at(5i)" ]
   end
   end
end
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `belongs_to :place` in `favorite.rb`?

Comment: Thanks - no I have it one line down, just forgot to copy it over.  Will update my question.

Comment: Did you define your own controller class out of ActiveAdmin DSL  on purpose? https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/8-custom-actions.md#modifying-the-controller

Comment: @nistvan - I typically have most of my controller code outside of activeadmin unless I get an error.  Is it proper to put it inside?  I will update my answer at the bottom with what else I have in my my admin/place.rb. I'm very new to the whole coding thing, so would appreciate any insight.

Comment: I think you should try to use the controller block and the index block instead of partial. Maybe that's why you get name error.

Comment: @nistvan I don't have a partial like _index.html.erb.  I'm trying to use index.html.erb & def index in my controller.  Not sure if I understand your comment - is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.  Basically, these two things fixed it:

1. Was making favorite_places polymorphic as well as favorites, didn't need to do that because only favorites should have been polymorphic.  So now,

   ```
   class FavoritePlace < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :favorite, as: :favorited, dependent: :destroy
   end
   ```
2. Didn't specify the user in ***favorite_places_controller.rb*** Should say:

   ```
   def index
     @places = current_user.favorite_places.all
   end
   ```